# Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml in my React native projects

Tags: android, react-native, maven, gradle, jcenter

my react native projects working well , today when i build it will through an error the error statement is
*FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/users/Documents/MyProject/Project_Name/node_modules/react-native-create-thumbnail/android/build.gradle' line: 114
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-create-thumbnail'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-create-thumbnail:implementation'.
> Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.+.
> Required by:
> project :react-native-create-thumbnail
> > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway*
> and i searched and got for remove jcenter() from my build.gradle ..what to do not get any idea. my android/build.gradle is

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.20'
        ffmpegKitPackage = "audio"
        ffmpegKitPackage = "full-gpl"
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "19.2.0"

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
        classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

please help what to do now??

Answer (score 1):

Repository Bintray/JCenter was sunset on 1 May 2021.

https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

Please remove `jcenter()` from your repository list.

Probably you need a little refresh versions of tools you used.

Comment: What do you do with libraries which are present only in jcenter